# "undefined reference to `strnstr'" when installing cminpack

Tags: c, ubuntu, installation, string.h

I am installing [cminpack](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/cminpack/cminpack.html) 1.1.2 on a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10.

When running `sudo make` in the cminpack folder, the folloing error occurs at 52%:

```
[ 52%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/genf77tests.dir/genf77tests.c.o
/usr/lib/cminpack-1.1.2/examples/genf77tests.c: In function ‘main’:
/usr/lib/cminpack-1.1.2/examples/genf77tests.c:44: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/lib/cminpack-1.1.2/examples/genf77tests.c:86: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
Linking C executable genf77tests
CMakeFiles/genf77tests.dir/genf77tests.c.o: In function `main':
genf77tests.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `strnstr'
genf77tests.c:(.text+0x2a9): undefined reference to `strnstr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [examples/genf77tests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/genf77tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have looked inside `genf77tests.c`, and `#include <string.h>` is present, so I don't see why there is a problem finding `strnstr`.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strnstr` is not standard C; as far as I can see, it's provided on the BSD UNIX family.

Still, if the only problem in your compilation is that one you can provide its prototype<sup>1</sup> and add to the files to be compiled one that contains its implementation (for example [this one](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=it#hA5OSqyPSCE/trunk/os/libstring/strnstr.c&q=strnstr&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc)).

---

1. Actually, you may not even need it: if the compilation gets to the linking stage and fails just there, you can solve throwing in just the implementation of `strnstr`.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. I just #included my own strnstr.c in the problem file.

Comment: @Bill: great, but in general you shouldn't `#include` .c files, you should instead provide the prototype in a `.h` and compile and link the `.c` as is done with the other files. (although, for a quick hack like this I don't know if it's worth trying to change the Makefile and everything `:)` )

Answer (score 3):

`strnstr` is a non-standard function. Specifically, it is not included in Glibc. Whoever wrote genf77test.c did not test it on Linux/glibc...